# Which is better Promise.all or nested async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have two blocks of code. First is using `async await`

```
  async sendEmailNotifications() {
    try {
      const users = await User.find(...)

      const promises = users.map(async(user) => {
        const _promises = user.appId.map(async(app) => {
            const todayVisitorsCount = await Session.count({...})
            const yesterdayVisitorsCount = await UserSession.count({...})
            const emailObj = {
              todayVisitorsCount,
              yesterdayVisitorsCount
            }
            const sendNotification = await emailService.analyticsNotification(emailObj)
        })
        await Promise.all(_promises)
      })
      return promises
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
(await sendEmailNotifications())
```

And then I have using `Promise.all`

```
    sendEmailNotifications() {
      const users = await User.find(...)
      const promises = users.map((user) => {
        const allPromises = []
        user.appId.map((app) => {
          allPromises.push(UserSession.count({...}))
          allPromises.push(Session.count({...}))
        })
        const data = await Promise.all(allPromises)
        const emailObj = {
          todayVisitorsCount: data[0],
          yesterdayVisitorsCount: data[1]
        }
        const sendNotification = await emailService.analyticsNotification(emailObj)
      })
      return promises
  }


  sendNotification.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Now I need to know which piece of code will faster execute? One is with series(async await) and one is with parellel(Promise.all). Which has better performance?

Comment: Nested async await will serialize your calls wheras promise.all will parallize them. So it depends on what you need.

Comment: Check this out - https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789

Comment: In your first snippet you were mapping over `user.appId`. That loop is totally gone from your second snippet, why? They hardly are comparable now.

Comment: In your first snippet, you were returning an array of promises, but not waiting for them. You need to use `Promise.all` on them another time: `return Promise.all(promises)`. Also I doubt that you want to return an error object - if you cannot handle an exception, just let it bubble.

Comment: @Bergi *you were mapping over user.appId* In both the snippet I am looping over `user.appId` (Pls look). *In your first .... time: return Promise.all(promises)* No I am returning `promises` and using await `(await sendEmailNotifications())`. *if you cannot handle an exception* I will handle it (Question is something for different purpose)

Comment: @Profer Oh now I see you're doing `user.appId.map` in the second snippet as well, but you are throwing away the resulting array - it should've been a `forEach` or just plain `for … of` loop there if you insist on collecting all the promises one big array. However, after waiting for all the promises in that array you only use the first two results (`data[0]` and `data[1]`) and throw away the rest. I don't think that's what you want? (Or at least it's not equivalent to your first snippet, which sends a notification for every `app`).

Comment: @Profer "*No I am returning `promises` and using `await sendEmailNotifications()`*" But that `promises` is an array, your `await` will not wait for the individual promises inside that array. You still need to use `Promise.all` on it.

Comment: @Bergi Okay thank you got it,

Comment: @arnonuem isn't javascript and node.js single-threaded? Meaning, they can only do concurrency rather than parallel execution. Concurrency isn't at all times faster than sequential bec only a single thread processes the task left and right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first code, you have two separate `await` statements:

```
        const todayVisitorsCount = await Session.count({...})
        const yesterdayVisitorsCount = await UserSession.count({...})
```

whereas in the second, you only have one, before a `Promise.all`:

```
const data = await Promise.all(allPromises)
```

In the first code, the second Promise will only initialize after the first Promise has finished, resulting in a longer time required before the script ends. For example:

```js
const fn = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

console.log('start');
(async () => {
  await fn();
  await fn();
  console.log('two awaits done');
})();

(async () => {
  await Promise.all([fn(), fn()]);
  console.log('Promise.all done');
})();
```

The version without `Promise.all` pauses the function when the first call of `fn()` is made, and waits for the Promise returned by `fn()` to resolve (1000 ms) before proceeding to the next line. The next line calls `fn()` again, and the `await` waits for it to complete (1000 more ms).

In contrast, the `Promise.all` version calls both `fn()`s immediately - both Promises are initialized, and the `await` that pauses the function is waiting for *both* Promises to complete. There's no down time between the initialization of the first Promise and the initialization of the second Promise.

So, the `Promise.all` version will run more significantly more quickly than the version with two `await`s. Using `Promise.all` will be preferable *unless* the first Promise (`UserSession.count`) **must** be completed before the second Promise (`Session.count`) starts.

With destructuring and without unnecessary variables, this is how I would clean up your `Promise.all` code, you might consider it to be a bit more readable:

```
async sendEmailNotifications() {
  const users = await User.find();
  return users.map(async (user) => {
    const [todayVisitorsCount, yesterdayVisitorsCount] = await Promise.all([
      UserSession.count(),
      Session.count()
    ]);
    await emailService.analyticsNotification({ todayVisitorsCount, yesterdayVisitorsCount });
  });
}
```

Comment: The other (admitedly rather unlikely) scenario is if `Session.count` and `UserSession.count` interact in a bad way for some strange reason and take longer if running together (maybe odd database contention?) so serial would end up faster than parallel... as I said, unlikely but worth bearing in mind in certain situations.

Comment: It's not that it "initializes promises," it's that it *starts operations*. That's the salient point. `await Session.count({})` followed by `await User.count({})` means that `User.count({})` isn't called until `Session.count({})`'s promise fulfills, so it doesn't start its operation until `Session.count({})`'s promise fulfills. If the operations should be done in parallel, it's important to start them both up-front, then wait for their results.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder CertainPerformance It is daunting hear breaking. Then what is the use of `async await` if it takes higher execution time.

Comment: @Profer `await` is *not* a substitute for `Promise.all` - they do two different things. `await` is a substitute for `Promise.prototype.then` (mostly), to make asynchronous code look flatter and more readable, for the most part. See how all of the snippets everywhere on this page use `await` - it *is* useful, no matter whether you use `Promise.all` or not. `Promise.all` returns a Promise that resolves when each in the array of passed Promises resolves, which is also useful in certain situations, including this one.

Comment: @Profer - When you want to do things one after another, `async`/`await` is much easier to follow. Whenever you want things in parallel, just use `Promise.all` as CertainPerformance showed (which you might use with `await` in order to wait for all of them to finish before continuing).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder CertainPerformance I gotttt it now. `async await` is the replacement for `.then` syntax rather than the `Promise.all`. Here `async await` would have been useful if I had used `todayVisitorsCount ` value in `UserSession.count({...})` query!!! Thankyou very much both of you.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hey... Can you please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3hngf1kv/2/) Why I am getting undefined in `[[PromiseValue]]` ? Is it necessary to return something why looping over the async function?

Comment: @Profer `async` functions automatically return Promises. If there is no `return` statement in the async function, it'll resolve to `undefined`, otherwise it'll resolve to whatever expression was `return`ed. When using the Promise constructor, If you want the resolve value to *be* something, call `resolve` with it, eg `resolve('foo')`

Comment: @CertainPerformance let's say what's called in Promise.all are `await axios.get`. Will the it wait for the result of the 1st executed axios call before proceeding to execute the rest? Or will it already execute the rest while waiting for the response? In the context of concurrency and not parallelism.

Comment: You mean `Promise.all([await someFn(), await someFn()])`? That would execute in serial and would defeat the purpose of using `Promise.all`, since you'd be passing the already resolved values to `Promise.all`, instead of the Promises.